# How would I create a hard fork in my fork of monero?

Tags: monero-forks, hard-fork

I added a version 15 in the hardforks.cpp file in the src/hardforks/ directory and compiled it. I launched the newly compiled daemon and it does not show the version 15 as actually existing.

Are there any other files for the hard fork that need to actually exist on my custom monero fork?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what you need to do. You have to mine up to the height it's set to of course. Also reset the mainnet_hard_fork_version_1_till variable to 0 (same file) since you presumably start with a fresh chain. If you don't start with a fresh chain, punch yourself in the face a few times and reconsider.

Comment: What does the mainnet_hard_fork_version_1_till variable mean/do?

Comment: It says "if height < this height, don't bother calculating which version it is". It's an optimization.